# max-width and max-height not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a dailymotion widget into a div and restrict its max width and height

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
<div max-height="400" max-width="400">

<div class="dailymotion-widget" data-placement="5ae8f699977fa0001314d656"> 
</div>
<script>(function(w,d,s,u,n,e,c){w.PXLObject = n; w[n] = w[n] || function(){(w[n].q =w[n].q || []).push(arguments);};w[n].l = 1 * new Date();e = d.createElement(s); e.async = 1; e.src = u;c = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(e,c);})(window, document, "script", "//api.dmcdn.net/pxl/client.js","pxl");</script>

</div>
```

I also tried to use  instead of  but the widget woudnt show at all

Comment: Shouldn't `<div max-height="400" max-width="400">` be `<div style="max-height:400; max-width:400">`?

Comment: The `max-height` property wont work there. you need to give fix property like `height="400px"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use CSS properties which means you need to use this syntax:

```
<div style="max-height:400px; max-width:400px">
```